# Drools - Check if map exist consecutive dates

Tags: java, date, dictionary, drools

I have collection (Map) contain data of 7 days. Keys of the hashmap are dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD
I need to create a rule to check if a string exists inside a List[String] in all days and all days are consecutive dates. Is there a way that i could do it?

I'm trying using contains but it's not include checking of consecutive dates.

```
    rule "bonus A"

    lock-on-active true
        when
        dataBinding : DataBinding($data : data)     items : List( size > 6 ) 
           from collect(  List(this contains "1" &&
                                this contains "2" &&
                                this contains "3" ) from $data.values )  then
             dataBinding.addPoint(7.5);       
 end
```

And here is my code

```
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put("2015-08-03", Arrays.asList("2", "3", "1", "4"));
        data.put("2015-08-05", Arrays.asList("2", "3", "1", "4"));
        data.put("2015-08-04", Arrays.asList("2", "3", "1", "4"));
        data.put("2015-08-07", Arrays.asList("2", "3", "1", "4"));
        data.put("2015-08-06", Arrays.asList("2", "3", "1", "4"));
        data.put("2015-08-09", Arrays.asList("2", "3", "1", "4"));
        data.put("2015-08-08", Arrays.asList("2", "3", "1", "4"));
        DataBinding dataBinding = new DataBinding();
        dataBinding.setData(data);

        ksession.insert(dataBinding);
        ksession.fireAllRules();
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you write a static method checking whether a set of seven String values denotes seven consecutive dates:

```
static boolean consecutive (Set<String> dates){
    // ...
}
```

and add a constraint to the rule:

```
rule "bonus A"
when
    dataBinding : DataBinding($data : data)
    eval( consecutive( $data.keySet() ) )   
    items : List( size > 6 ) ...
```

There is no simple way around this.

You may add this method as a DRL function, with only minor changes in the syntax - see the Drools manual.